# How do i make my code IntelliSense friendly in a React Native Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I recently started a React Native project using the atomic design aproach. What y want to do is document my atoms and molecules(React Native components) so i can read the props types and names from VSCode intellisense.
I tried using JS docs in my components as follows:

```
    /**
 *
 *
 * @param {function} onPress
 * @param {string} text
 * @param {boolean} disable
 * @returns TouchableOpacity
 */
function Boton(text, onPress, disable) {
   if (disable) {
       styles.boton.opacity = 0;
   }
    return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}  disabled={disable} style={styles.boton}>
        <Text style={styles.texto}>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    boton: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.PRIMARY,
        padding: 5,
        borderRadius: 36,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    texto: {
        color: Colors.TEXT,
        fontSize: 13,
    },
});

export default Boton;
```

This file is later exported in a file called index.js inside the same directory as follows:

```
export {default as Boton} from './Boton';
```

Then i import the component in the file i want to use it but my intelliSense only shows this:

[No intelliSense auto completion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzOGc.png)

How can i make my intelliSense to show the description and parameters of my functions so i can make my code clearer?

Btw i am using some libraries to make imports easier using aliases, does this have anything to do?
this are the Alias libraries:

```
"eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.1.2",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0"
```